# Add +1 in Quarter

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select max(QTR) from A.Table;

---2020Q4
```

In A.Table QTR column is in 'YYYYQQ' format

An expected outcome to be: Addition of QTR

```
---2021Q1
```

(ie. 2021Q1 is the max QTR means: Expected Outcome: 2021Q2
2021Q2 is the max QTR means: Expected Outcome: 2021Q3
2021Q3 is the max QTR means: Expected Outcome: 2021Q4
2021Q4 is the max QTR means Expected Outcome: 2022Q1)

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to convert the value to a date by adding the appropriate number of months to the first of the year.  Then convert back to YYYYQ format:

```
select to_char(add_months(to_date(substr(yyyyq, 1, 4) || '-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), substr(yyyyq, -1) * 3), 'YYYY"Q"Q')
from (select '2021Q4' as yyyyq from dual)
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff  yup it satisfy for all Quarter values.